# Generate random numbers in a random fashion

Tags: probability, algorithms, random-variables, random-functions

How can I generate 9 random numbers between 1 to 9,without repetition, one after another. Its like:
Lets assume that the first random number generated is 4, then the next random number has to be in [1, 9] - {4}.
My first approach was to add each randomly generated number to a set, and so avoid duplication. But then in worse cases, like we have already generated 6 and we have to generate 3 more numbers, the process goes a little slow. ANd when the range is changed from [1, 9] to [1, 1000], this approach doesn't sound correct.
Can anyone suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Random numbers without repetitions are not very random. Maybe you look for random permutations.

Comment: Here is a related question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947612/generating-m-distinct-random-numbers-in-the-range-0-n-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) gives an efficient way of generating a permutation uniformly at random.  From an initial list, it performs $O(n)$ swaps.

Afterwards, we can just read the entries from the permutation.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for...thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to find a permutation of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. There are $9!$ such permutations in general, and picking one at random will produce an ordering of the numbers.

The easiest way to do it is to have a way of selecting a random element from a set. That way, you just perform the process:

- Pick random number $x$ from $S$
- Replace $S$ with $S\setminus \{x\}$
- If $S$ is not empty, repeat first step.

Comment: array based implementation of this algorithm will work...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First generate generate a random number 1 to 9; lets say you get 4

Next generate a random number 1 to 8 Lets say you get 5 so the number you use is the 5th one you have not already used so it would be 6.

Next generate a random number 1 to 7 Lets say you get 2 so the number you use is the 2nd one you have not already used so it would be 2.

Repeat for all numbers.

Comment: yes...just got this algorithm [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle)

Answer (score 1):

generate any number k
select number (k mod 10), enumerate the remaining 9 numbers in sequence
generate any number k
select number (k mod 9), enumerate the remaining 8 numbers in sequence
etc.

Comment: Velcome to the site! However, when answering questions, you should try to be more helpful, such as giving reasons for your answer, which you did'nt do here.